# How to block internet access of all apps (except browser) when using 3g usb modem?

Tags: firewall, cellular-data

Is there any app that helps me to block all apps for accessing the internet when using 3g modem?

Comment: Do you mind clicking a few buttons yourself to switch profiles/etc or do you want it to block internet access *automatically* when you connect your modem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little Snitch is like a Ferrari if you can afford it.

There is a now discontinued little app that does the same for 10.6 and before Yosemite.

[TCPBlock](https://web.archive.org/web/*/tcpblock.wordpress.com):

Allows you to select who is to be blocked and who not.

[image: TCPblock]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (assuming you are using Mac OS X), but you're not going to like the answer: [pfctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/pfctl.8.html). (Prior to OS X 10.7 Lion, the firewall was [ipfw](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/ipfw.8.html).)

Also, alternatively, you can use the [GUI](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/165) to configure pfctl (or ipfw).

---

Also, OS X includes an [application firewall](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1810) :

> ### Allowing specific applications
>
> #### To allow a specific app to receive incoming connections, add it using Firewall Options:
>
> - Open System Preferences.
> - Click the Security or Security & Privacy icon.
> - Select the Firewall tab.
> - Click the lock icon in the preference pane, then enter an administrator name and password.
> - Click the Firewall Options button
> - Click the Add Application (+) button.
> - Select the app you want to allow incoming connection privileges for.
> - Click Add.
> - Click OK.
> - You can also remove any apps listed here that you no longer want to allow by clicking the Remove App (-) button.

---

There is also a third party application that is very popular called [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) that will do what you ask.

---

Although I wouldn't recommend it for your purposes unless you were using it to learn about it for its own sake, OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and above includes a [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man7/sandbox.7.html) facility (be sure to read the man pages listed under "SEE ALSO.")